# .Net 8 Blazor with MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

Microsoft announced Blazor will come SSR (without websocket connection) in .NET 8. I'm using ASP.NET Core 7 MVC with Blazor components. Today I updated my project to .Net 8 but it still uses websocket connections on blazor side. How to I do configuration in Program.cs and other pages.

This is my `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(); 
app.MapBlazorHub();
```

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

My `Index.cshtml` file which calls Blazor component:

```
<component type="typeof(DoldurExampleList)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
// or
@( await Html.RenderComponentAsync<DoldurExampleList>(RenderMode.Server))
```

Result:

[browser console websocket result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s3y2.png)

Comment: I think we have to use `@attribute [RenderModeServer]`, [here is the sample](https://github.com/CoderFoundry/BlazorRenderModes/blob/330969abb2c686db77d4f4c2408be9aada51efda/Server/Pages/MovieListSignalR.razor#L4).